# Angular - refresh jwt token

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

I am having a backend in Laravel and making an app in Ionic. I am using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#-login-with-email-and-password) on the frontend side and [this package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication) on the laravel side for JWT authentication. Since I need to have token for users until they log out, I need a way to refresh their token somehow. I am not sure how to do this, would it be better to have all routes requesting auth token and sending 401 response if not present, and then do token refresh, or refreshing a token with timer on the frontend side and how to actually do that?

This is is my routes file:

```
Route::group(['jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']], 'prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'Api'], function() {
  Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
  Route::get('user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');
  Route::get('comment', 'AuthenticateController@comment');
  Route::get('articles/latest', 'ArticlesController@latest');
  Route::get('articles/by-score', 'ArticlesController@byScore');
  Route::get('article/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');
  Route::get('comments', 'CommentsController@index');
  Route::get('comments/{id}', 'CommentsController@show');
  Route::post('comments/create', 'CommentsController@store');
  Route::put('comments/update', 'CommentsController@update');
  Route::delete('comments/delete', 'CommentsController@destroy');
  Route::post('article/upvote', 'VotesController@upvote');
  Route::delete('article/upvote/delete', 'VotesController@destroyUpVote');
  Route::post('article/challenge/vote', 'VotesController@challengeVote');
  Route::delete('article/challenge/vote/delete', 'VotesController@destroyChallengeVote');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past is to do authorization on *every* request and then do create a new token when the expiry of the token in your database is within some length of time. For me, a 1 hour token would refresh if a user is still active within the last 15 minutes. Then, if the token is refreshed, set the new token inside of Laravel and invalidate the old. Or you could just extend the refresh time in the database. My recommendation would be to have some expire_time set when the token is initially created. And then return a 401 if the token is expired.